# Form data not submitting correctly

Tags: php, mysql

So I have created a simple form that's supposed to send the data inputted to a table. The problem I have is whenever the character count in the 'content' field is over a certain number, I press submit and all the fields empty and none of the data is sent to the table. I should get a message that says 'post published successfully' once submitted, but it doesn't happen for the above reason and I have no clue why.

I then have to go to localhost and edit the field there. Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $post_title = $_POST['title'];
    $post_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $post_author = $_POST['author'];
    $post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $post_content = $_POST['content'];
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


    if($post_title == '' or $post_keywords == '' or $post_content == ''
    or $post_author == '') {

        echo "<script>alert('Please fill the empty fields!')</script>";

        exit();
    }
    else {

        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "../images/$post_image");

        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `posts` 
        (post_title, post_date, post_author, post_image, 
        post_keywords, post_content) 
        values ('$post_title', '$post_date', '$post_author', '$post_image', 
        '$post_keywords', '$post_content')";

        if(mysqli_query($connect, $insert_query)) {

            echo "<center><h1>Post Published Successfully!</h1></center>";
        }
    }

}
?>

<body>

    <form method = "post" action = "insert_post.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

        <table width = "600" align = "center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan = "6"><h1 style = "font-family: 'Fjalla One'; color: #575757;">Insert new post here</h1></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><!--TITLE-->
                <td align = "right" size = "30px" style = "font-family: 'Fjalla One'; color: #575757; font-size: 20px;">Post Title:</td>
                <td><input type = "text" name = "title"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><!--AUTHOR-->
                <td align = "right" size = "30px" style = "font-family: 'Fjalla One'; color: #575757; font-size: 20px;">Post Author:</td>
                <td><input type = "text" name = "author"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><!--KEYWORDS-->
                <td align = "right" size = "30px" style = "font-family: 'Fjalla One'; color: #575757; font-size: 20px;">Post Keywords:</td>
                <td><input type = "text" name = "keywords"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><!--IMAGE-->
                <td align = "right" style = "font-family: 'Fjalla One'; color: #575757; font-size: 20px;">Post Image:</td>
                <td><input type = "file" name = "image"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><!--CONTENT-->
                <td align = "right" style = "font-family: 'Fjalla One'; color: #575757; font-size: 20px;">Post Content</td>
                <td><textarea name = "content" cols = "40" rows = "20"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align = "center" colspan = "6"><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Publish" ></td>
            </tr>

    </form>
```

Comment: What's your POST limit for the localhost server?

Comment: side note: you should use parameterized queries. in its current state, your code is prone to SQL-injections. just imagine someone POSTing something like `'; DROP TABLE posts; --`

Comment: what's the column type for the `post_image` column? and what do you want to do here, use the file "name" or the image itself?

Comment: I stood around this question long enough and I don't generally do that anymore. If the answer given below solved the question, then consider accepting it in order to mark it as solved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- use the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including some MySQL error handling to give yourself a better idea of the problem - something like this:

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $post_title = $_POST['title'];
    $post_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $post_author = $_POST['author'];
    $post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $post_content = $_POST['content'];
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


    if($post_title == '' or $post_keywords == '' or $post_content == ''
    or $post_author == '') {

        echo "<script>alert('Please fill the empty fields!')</script>";

        exit();
    }
    else {

        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "../images/$post_image");

        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `posts` 
        (post_title, post_date, post_author, post_image, 
        post_keywords, post_content) 
        values ('$post_title', '$post_date', '$post_author', '$post_image', 
        '$post_keywords', '$post_content')";

        if(mysqli_query($connect, $insert_query)) {

            echo "<center><h1>Post Published Successfully!</h1></center>";
        } else echo  "MySQL Error description: " . mysqli_error($connect);
    }

}
?>
```

Do not use this in a production environment as you shouldn't be displaying technical error messages to end users - especially as you aren't escaping your raw input leaving you very prone to SQL injection.

---

**EDIT:**

Op pasted error message, showing it was a `'` character in the string submitted causing MySQL to error - solution is to pass every variable submitted through `mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $variable);`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this now

Comment: MySQL Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 're back with even more news to excite fans. In a recent post on their social me' at line 5

Comment: You need to escape your MySQL as you have a ' character which is altering the SQL call - in a way you're accidentally injecting yourself

Comment: @JBithell I don't think that's the only problem here. The `post_image` column they're trying to insert their file with is unknown as to what they're wanting to do here. Use the filename or insert the image/blob itself.

Comment: @JBithell do you have any idea how I'd do that exactly? I'm still quite new to php